# addOnCompleteListener documentReference variable show null Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAb0z.jpg)

I am using Android studio to connect firestore and Android app. How can i store data inside listener to use after listener calling but is always show null value. It seems like `addOnCompleteListener` goes in background and `documentReference` variable use first how can i fix it. 
and
**documentReference variable show null value**

```
    DocumentReference documentReference;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("CustomerUser")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                documentReference = document.getDocumentReference("businessUsedID");
                                Log.d("REF_DATA", document.getId() + " => " + documentReference.getId());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w("REF_DATA", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.i("REF_DATA", "onEvent: "+documentSnapshot.getString("PaymentMode"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: You're trying to use `documentReference` immediately when it's set later in an async callback.  You need to move your `documentReference.addSnapshotListener` after you set `documentReference`.  Also the fact that you're setting the variable in a loop is suspicious.

Comment: `documentReference.addSnapshotListener` not working inside for loop and if block but  
`Log.d("REF_DATA", document.getId() + " => " + documentReference.getId());`  inside for loop working fine